# CSS alternative to center

Tags: center, css

People frown upon the `center` tag, but for me it *always* works *just the way I want it*. Nevertheless, `center` is deprecated so I'll make an effort.

Now I see many people suggest the cryptic CSS `margin: 0 auto;` but I can't even get it to work (see fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/1269/)). Other people will go modify `position` or `display`, but that always breaks something else.

How can I center a `span` using css so that it behaves exactly like the `center` tag?

```
<div class="container">
  <span class='btn btn-primary'>Click me!</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Span` is an inline element, and the `margin: 0 auto` for centering only works on non-inline elements that have a width that is less than 100%.

One option is to set an alignment on the container, though this probably isn't what you want for this situation:

```
div.container { text-align: center }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/1270/

The other option is to change the display property of the `span`:

```
/* needs some extra specificity here to avoid the display being overwritten */
span.btn.btn-primary { 
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Using `display: table` eliminates the need to hard code a specific width.  It will shrink or grow as appropriate for its content.

http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/1271/

Comment: That's the kind of thing I hate about CSS. `display: table`, WTF?

Comment: Well, it works.  `Table` is just a poorly chosen value name and doesn't really describe how it flows like some of the other display property values (inline, block, inline-block, etc.).

Comment: Another thing to note is that you'll need to remove any `float`s with `float: none;` if you have any.

Comment: No thanks, I will stick to the good old `<center>` which is way easier and faster... deprecated or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `.container { text-align:center; }` so that everything inside `div.container` will be centered.

In general, there are two ways centering things.

1. To center inline elements (such as text, spans and images) inside their parents, set `text-align: center;` on the parent.
2. To center a block level element (such as header, div or paragraph), it must first have a specified width (`width: 50%;` for example).  Then set the left and right margins to auto.  Your example of `margin: 0 auto;` says that the top and bottom margin should be 0 (this doesn't matter for centering) ad that the left and right margins should be auto - they should be equal to each other.

The `<center>` element is really just a block-level element with `text-align:center;`.  If you sent `border: solid red 1px;` on it, you can see that it's 100% wide, and that everything inside it is centered.  If you change `text-align` to left, then its children are no longer centered.  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/KatieK/MgcDU/1275/.  Perhaps you should just consider your `<div class="container">` with `text-align:center; }` to be equivalent to `<center>`.

Comment: Are you saying an inline element needs to be wrapped in a parent just for centering if its siblings are not to be centered?

Comment: What would an inline element be centered *against* if its siblings are not to be centered?

Comment: So that I'm answering the right question, can you give an example including `center`?

Comment: How do other UN-centered siblings fit into your example?

Comment: The new `span.btn` element isn't a sibling of `<span class='btn btn-primary'>`; it's a sibling of `<center>`.  The `<center>` element is acting as `div.container`, with `height: 100%;` and `text-align:center;` set on it.

Answer (score 1):

You make the span block level, give it a width so margin:auto works

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faeLG/)

```
.center {
         display:block;
         margin:auto auto;
         width:150px; //all rules upto here are important the rest are styling
         border:1px solid black;
         padding:5px;
         text-align:center;
}
```

UPDATE: In order to NOT specify a width and have natural width of element on the span you will have to use textalign on parent

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faeLG/1/)

```
.container{text-align:center}
.center {
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:5px;
}
```

Comment: No. I don't want to have to specify a width just for centering. No way.

Comment: @Randomblue well if it doesn't have a width specified it is still centered - it just takes up the full width! think about it... Without width what is to be centered.

Comment: I want it to take its "natural width". Is it really that difficult with CSS? `center` preserves "natural width".

Comment: Block level elements (those with `display:block` by default or a new specification) are 100% wide until you change the width.

Comment: `0px`. OMG, I hate CSS. For me, `0px` should be "zero width", not "natural width".

Comment: You'll have to use text-align on parent for what you are after (see update)

Comment: or you can use display:table; margin:0 auto; as another poster suggested (though dubious ;))

Comment: @PaulSullivan `width: 0px;` won't give the effect of centering a block element. For example, see http://jsfiddle.net/5c4ec/. The `DIV` becomes 0 pixels wide, but the content (the button) extends from the left of the 0 pixel wide centered `DIV`. `display: inline-block;` is closer to "natural width", but it doesn't center with `margin: 0 auto;`. The best solution in a case like that is to just wrap the element in a new element with `text-align: center;` applied. `margin: 0 auto;` is almost exclusively for cases where you know the centered element's width.

Comment: @thirdender Agreed - as soon as the op required 'natural width' I updated with text-align.

Answer (score -1):

`<span>` is an inline element. `<div>` is a block element. That's why it is not centering.

```
<div class="container" style='float:left; width:100%; text-align:center;'>
  <span class='btn btn-primary'>Click me!</span>
</div>
```

You can center the content of span only when you convert it into block, using 'inline-block' style.

Comment: The included bootstrap library is handling the application of the `display: inline-block;` property.

Answer (score -1):

Your parent element needs to have a larger width in order to let a child element be positioned within it.  After that the trick with `margin: 0 auto;` is getting the parent and child container `position` and `display` values to be compatible with each other.

```
.container {
  border: 2px dashed;
  width: 100%;}

.btn {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 25%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rgY4D/2/

Comment: `width: 25%`? Surely not. I don't want the button to change width when adjusting the window size!

Comment: @Randomblue it is an example. You could set a fixed width but percentages are very common with responsive design.