# How to center div block of unknown width?

Tags: css, html

I am working on removing tables from my site, and just learning the div tricks involved. My [home page](http://r0k.us/rock/games/CoH/HallsOfHeroes/) currently has a centered table nested in another table. Removing the outer table was a bit tricky for someone just learning non-table methods, but it's done.

My problem is, the inner table is super-easy to center ("margin:0 auto" in the CSS), but its [div equivalent](http://r0k.us/rock/junk/HoH_DivVsTable.png) is not.  The div will center if I specify an absolute width (such as 640px), but since I'm designing with the user's font size (not something I specify), I don't know how wide it will actually be for a given user.

I've simplified the home page and have it online ([test.html](http://r0k.us/rock/games/CoH/HallsOfHeroes/test.html) and [HoH.css](http://r0k.us/rock/games/CoH/HallsOfHeroes/HoH.css)  Here is an overview [image](http://r0k.us/rock/junk/HoH_HPproblem.jpg) of test.html.

Sorry for all the links.  But with a floaty thing inside another floaty thing, I don't know what is relevant.  The file test.html contains 63 lines of formatted HTML. The 640px hr is there for reference only; it will not be part of the final page.

PS: I'm removing the tables because when I asked for site reviews, the first comment almost everyone had was, "get rid of the damn tables".

Comment: At present, this question is pretty localized.  But briefly, put `text-align: center;` on the `h1`.  You may need to work with how that box on the right is aligned with respect to the `h1`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286597/css-alternative-to-center/14286703 for more on centering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you shouldn't worry about users font size because all modern browsers zoom whole page, not only font size, and everybody will be happy with your fixed width.

Also you can use EM values instead of PX, 1em = font size in px. You can change 640px to 40em if you have 16px font size. If someone have for example twice bigger font, he will get twice wider block.

And if you want css-solution for unknown width block centering, you can use `inline-block` and `text-align:center`: http://jsfiddle.net/rBc4T/

Answer (score 0):

use CSS and jQuery -

css -

```
#divID{ left:50%;}
```

jQuery -

```
(function(){
var marginLeft = $('#divID').width();
$('#divID').css('marginLeft','-'+ marginLeft /2 +'px');
});
```