# how to align the content to center of page using css

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following code to add the text in end of page,

```
@media print
{
    .page:after
    {
        content: "copyrighted data";
        color: #e7792e;
        font-size: 14px;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

How to align the above content to center of page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS alternative to center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286597/css-alternative-to-center)

Comment: Its not duplicate, i'm trying to center the content within media rule

Comment: How does the media rule change anything? A media rule just injects css when something (in your case "print"). It doesn't actually do anything to the code inside.

Comment: @Dude Ya of course, its different. In ordinary html if you specify text-align: center - it will align the content to center but in media rule its different. For your kind information: i'm not aligning a div content, dynamically am inserting content and aligning it

Comment: Everything you've described shouldn't affect how it's rendered at all (except the media query which obviously only applies to printing).

Comment: check the various answers below

Comment: Yes. I saw them. They all have `text-align: center;`. I think the only problem you have is the container is not expanded. `left: 0; right: 0;` may be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?

```
.page:after {
    content: "copyrighted data";
    color: #e7792e;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Hrm. It works on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jhummel/PLZ5p/, however I can't test the print media query at the moment. So perhaps the rules differ when not on the screen

Comment: Notice, I added 'left: 0; right: 0;' as well as the 'text-align: center;'. I think that is required.

Comment: Ya ya just before only i noticed, now its working fine, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
text-align: center;
```

to your css

```
@media print
{
    .page:after
    {
        content: "copyrighted data";
        color: #e7792e;
        font-size: 14px;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work? This should center everything that you put in the class incase you want to add a background.

```
@media print
{
    .page:after
    {
        content: "copyrighted data";
        text-align:center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        color: #e7792e;
        font-size: 14px;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including "margin: 0 auto" in your style.