# Fixed width centered content without wrapper div

Tags: html, css

I have a div that should be full width (it has a background image that should span the whole page) and I want the content to have a fixed width and to be centered.

Is there a way to do this, without the `centered-content` div:

```
<div class="background">
  <div class="centered-content">My content</div>
</div>
```

This is what I want to achieve (with only *one* div):

[image]

**EDIT**: I don't want the text to be centered. I want a `400px` wide centered text box, that contains left aligned text.

Comment: why not put text-align: center to background class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286597/css-alternative-to-center

Comment: I don't want centered text, and I want a fixed with content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there *is* a solution to this problem, that I just figured out.

You can set a padding, with the use of `calc()`. Unfortunately it involves a division, which is [not properly supported by android](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).

```css
#container {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 6em calc((100% - 400px)/2);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin.<br>
  He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and divided by arches into stiff sections. The bedding was hardly able to cover it and seemed ready to slide off any moment.<br>
  His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked. "What's happened to me? " he thought. It wasn't a dream. His room, a proper human room although a little too small, lay peacefully between its four familiar walls.<br>
  A collection of textile samples lay spread out on the table - Samsa was a travelling salesman - and above it there hung a picture that he had recently cut out of an illustrated magazine and housed in a nice, gilded frame. It showed a lady fitted out with a fur hat and fur boa who sat upright, raising a heavy fur muff that covered the whole of her lower arm towards the viewer. Gregor then turned to look out the window at the dull weather. Drops<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the simplest solution is to add to your `class="centered-content"` `margin: 0 auto;`

```
<div class="background">
  <div class="centered-content">My content</div>
</div>

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.background {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
}
.centered-content {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 400px;
  background: #c01;
}
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bJnrd)

Comment: The OP explicitly mentioned "without the `centered-content` div".

Comment: use text-align:center

Comment: I don't want the `centered-content` div. I know how to center the div properly.

Comment: I don't want text to be centered, I want the whole block to be centered with a specific width.

Answer (score -1):

You want to get rid of the `centered-content` div, and still center the HTML with a fixed width? That is not really achievable, you could set the background image to the body so you can get rid of the `.background` div, but just one div that has a full-width background, but is also centered with a fixed width, is not possible.

---

## Edit

Ofcourse you can solve this with jQuery, here a little example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    fixedWidth = 800;
    padding = ($(window).width() - fixedWidth) / 2;
    $(".background").css({paddingLeft: padding+"px", paddingRight: padding+"px"});
});
```

Please keep in mind that this code is untested and you might have to change things. You also will need to have an `$(window).resize()` function to catch the screen width changing, as you will have to update the padding everytime the width changes.

Comment: The problem is that it's multiple full width divs in one page. So I can't just get rid of the `.background` div.

Comment: I would have thought that it's impossible as well, but I thought that maybe there are techniques now to achieve that (like flexible padding or something)

Comment: I have added it some code to my answer, you might find that helpfull.

Comment: No JavaScript is out of the question for layout.