# <center> tags will only center text but not image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a `<div>` element containing both text and image using `<center>` tags, but for some reason it only applies on the text and not the image.

**HTML**:

```
<body>
        <h1 align="center">Search For a Member</h1>
        <br>
        <br>
        <form action="SearchController" method="get">
            Enter the member's first name: <input type="text" style="width: 18em;" name="searchBox">
            <input style="width:6em;" type="submit" value="Search">
            <input style="width:6em;padding-left:7px;" type="submit" value="Back">
        </form>

        <center>
        <div class="profile">
            <img style="float:left;" src="default.jpg"height=100 width=100>
            First Name
            <br>
            Last Name
            <br>
        </div>
        </center>
</body>
```

**CSS**:

```
    <style>
    body {
        background-color: #BCD2EE;
        margin-left: 20%;
        margin-right: 20%;
        border: 1px outset #4876FF;
        border-width: 5px;
        padding: 10px 10px 30px 10px;
    }
    .profile {
        overflow: hidden;
        padding-top: 30px;
    }
    </style>
```

But if you'll try it, you'll see that only the text "First Name" and "Last Name" gets centered but not the picture. (I know you won't be able to see the picture `default.jpg`, but it will show you where the image would be).

Why won't the picture get centered? is it because of the `float:left;` property, which excludes the picture from the `<center>` tag?

If so, how can it be fixed?

Comment: Consider not using `<center>` [as it is deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html). There are many [alternative methods to center content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286597/css-alternative-to-center)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<img style="float:left;"`

You shouldn't have `style="float:left;"`

Remove that, and also add a line break `<br>` after the img tag

http://jsfiddle.net/jn8zgszy/

Comment: But I want the text "First Name" and "Last Name" to sit to the right of the picture, not below it.

Comment: Well, actually now that I see it, it's much nicer when the text is below the picture... I think I'll use it after all...

Comment: @so.very.tired Ah! Well I'm glad you like it haha! If you want the text to sit to the right the style you need to use isn't float:left, it's display:inline-block

Comment: Also, you can use a table to vertical align the text to the right. If you put the whole image inside a <span> with display:inline-block your original idea should work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float:left` inline styling from `img` tag

Change:

```
<img style="float:left;" src="default.jpg"height=100 width=100>
```

To:

```
<img src="default.jpg" height="100" width="100"><br />
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/23xa1nre/)**

Answer (score 0):

An alternative idea without the [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html) `<center>` tag, external CSS and tweaked form elements.

Centering is done via `.wrap { display: table; margin: 0 auto; }`

[Have a jsBin example!](http://jsbin.com/hebax/1/edit)

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
  <form action="SearchController" method="get">
        <legend>Search For a Member</legend>

        <label for="firstName">Enter the member's first name:</label>
        <input name="searchBox" id="firstName" type="text"> 

        <button type="submit">Search</button>       
        <button type="submit">Back</button>
  </form>

  <div class="profile">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100" />
    <dl>
      <dt>First Name</dt>
      <dd>Greg</dd>

      <dt>Last Name</dt>
      <dd>Norman</dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.wrap {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
form {
    padding: 10px;
}
legend {
    margin: 20px auto;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    display: table;
}
.profile img {
    margin: 10px 0 10px;
}
.profile dt {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.profile dd {
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted the Image and those text to be center and one below the other then you could simple give `text-align:center;` to your `.profile`

```
.profile{
  text-align:center;
}
```